# bind and unbind function with a name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to bind and unbind a function on click.
The problem is that I need the click event (also 'this' as the clicked element would be fine)

```
  function clickElement(e) {
  [...]
   //here I need event or this clicked element
  }
```

this would works, but doesn't have the event parameter

```
$('.clickme').on('click', clickElement)
```

this would works but I can't unbind the specific function

```
 $('.clickme').on('click', function(e){clickElement(e)})
```

this doesn't work:

```
 $('.clickme').on('click', clickElement(e))
```

why?

I need to use .on instead of .click because later I need to unbind clickElement and only clickElement like this:

```
  $('.clickme').off('click', clickElement);
```

Comment: it should be ok in the first case

Comment: That should work `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/f6qJF/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first choice is exactly what you need

```
 function clickElement(e) {
      console.log(e, this);      
  }

  $('.clickme').on('click', clickElement);
```

The reason why

```
$('.clickme').on('click', function(e){clickElement(e)})
$('.clickme').off('click', function(e){clickElement(e)})
```

does not work is because it is a new anonymous function and it will not map to the one you used in on(). If you need to do that, you would have to keep a reference to that.

```
var myFunc = function(e){clickElement(e); };
$('.clickme').on('click', myFunc ).data("fnc", myFunc);
```

and to remove it

```
var elem = $('.clickme');
elem.off('click', elem.data("fnc") );
```

Comment: I didn't realized .on('click', clickElement) what actually passing the click parameter -_- `ashamed`